# What is the best way to get call duration in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, call

I'm working on a Cordova application that needs to access information about phone calls. I need to know how long a call lasted to record this information in my application.

I have searched Cordova documentation and internet forums, but I couldn't find any clear information on how to access call duration in Cordova.

Is there any way to get call duration in Cordova? If so, how can I do it? Thank you in advance for your help

I tray this, but not success:

```js
 function onSuccess(result) {
    console.log('Call started');
    var startTime = new Date();
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        window.plugins.callNumber.onCallStateChanged(function (state) {
            if (state == "DISCONNECTED") {
                var endTime = new Date();
                var duration = endTime - startTime;
                console.log('Call ended, duração: ' + duration + 'ms');
            }
        });
    });
    console.log("Success:" + result);
}

function onError(result) {
    console.log("Error:" + result);
}

window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(onSuccess, onError, number);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the right plugin. Give a try to https://github.com/creacore-team/cordova-plugin-calllog

> Android only Cordova plugin to access the call history on a device.
> Results can be filtered through several parameters

Answer (score 0):

**Solved with successfull**:

```js
function onDeviceReady() {

  window.plugins.callLog.requestReadPermission((ev) => {
    console.log(ev)
    if (ev == 'OK') {
      let filters = [{
        "name": "number",
        "value": "%99973%",
        "operator": "like",
      }];
      window.plugins.callLog.getCallLog(filters, function (data) {
        console.log('info kay:', data);
      }, function (ev) {
        console.log('Errror112:', ev);
      });
    }
  })

}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```